# ASP.NET Web API Client receiving list of objects

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET Web API app, I have a query that is as such:

```
var cars = db.Cars.Where(x => x.budget < budget).GroupBy(Cars => Cars.carTypeID).ToList();
```

Now that I have the list cars that should be full of car objects grouped by carTypeID (This is only a test, I know it's impractical), how do I build the car objects on the client side once I return a response with the list?

EDIT:
Results are returned in JSON format fyi

Comment: Do you receive a list of cars in JSON format on the client side?

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot to add that the results are sent in JSON format

Comment: Can you share sample JSON?

Answer (score 1):

var javascriptObject = JSON.parse(jsonData);

Comment: Sorry but then what since that is stored in one variable rather than multiple variables to represent the multiple objects in the list

Comment: you can access to each one: javascriptObject[0], javascriptObject[1],javascriptObject[2], etc...